# Pattern matching ParseResult in unit test

Tags: scala, parsing

I'm stepping through my first Scala project, and looking at parser combinators in particular. I'm having trouble getting a simple unit test scenario to work, and trying to understand what I'm missing.

I'm stuck on pattern matching a ParseResult into the case classes of Success, Failure and Error. I can't get Scala to resolve the case classes. There's a few examples around of this, but they all seem to be using them inside something that extends of of the parser classes. For example the [tests on github](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators/blob/master/src/test/scala/scala/util/parsing/combinator/JavaTokenParsersTest.scala) are inside the same package. The example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348121/scala-parser-issues) is inside a class extending a parser.

The test i'm trying to write looks like:

```
package test.parsertests

import parser.InputParser // my sut   
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

import org.scalatest.FunSuite   
class SetSuite extends FunSuite {

  val sut = new InputParser()

  test("Parsing a valid command") {
    val result = sut.applyParser(sut.commandParser, "SOME VALID INPUT")
    result match {
       case Success(x, _) => println("Result: " + x.toString) // <-- not found: value Success
       case Failure(msg, _) => println("Failure: " + msg) // similar
       case Error(msg, _) => println("Error: " + msg) // similar
    }
  }
}
```

and the method I'm calling is designed to let me exersize each of my parsers on my SUT:

```
package parser

import scala.util.parsing.combinator._
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.syntactical._

class InputParser extends StandardTokenParsers  {

  def commandParser: Parser[Command] =
("Command " ~> coord ~ coord ~ direction) ^^ { case x ~ y ~ d => new Command(x, y, d) }

  def applyParser[T](p: Parser[T], c: String): ParseResult[T] = {
    val tokens = new lexical.Scanner(c)
    phrase(p)(tokens)

}
```

The fundamental issue is getting the case classes resolved in my test scope. Based on the [source](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators/blob/a082ed0d0699b9d0036a971db549d72cdb252d31/src/main/scala/scala/util/parsing/combinator/Parsers.scala) for the Parsers class, how can I get them defined? Can I resolve this with some additional import statements, or are they only accessible via inheritance? I've tried all the combinations that should resolve this issue, but I'm obviously missing something here.

Comment: Can post your InputParser code here or github gist ?

Comment: I have filled out more of the InputParser class code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right hand column FTW! I stumbled on an answer in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13780246/2658793). The problem was identifying the case classes as nested classes of Parsers.